# Select preceding-sibilings of element that contains child in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have code that looks like this

```
<div id="content">
 <p>text</p>
 <p>text1</p>
 <p>text3</p>

 <p><iframe></iframe></p>

 <p>text4</p>
 <p>text5</p>
</div>
```

I need to select all "p" elements before "p" that contains child "iframe", I tried something like this

`//div[@id='content']//p[iframe]/preceding-sibiling::p`

but with no luck.

I am stuck here for a few days so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath logic was actually fine! You just have a few typos it appears.

`//div[@id='content']/p[iframe]/preceding-`**sibiling**`::p`

You also don't need the extra `/` after the div block. Here's the full working xpath:

```
//div[@id='content']/p[iframe]/preceding-sibling::p
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I have fixed the typo but for some reason I still can not get it to wrok, could be it is some other problem tahan just the selectors. Code I wrote in a qustion is just aproctimation of the whole code but I thoght that I am using slectors the wrong way. I actualy have more than one p with iframe in this div and I tried to to append `p[iframe and position() = 2]` but that is not working ither.
Maby I`ll post bigger part of code later